# Hyperledger Composer deployment to Multiple Orgs Identity Error

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am studying and trying out to deploy a Hyperledger Composer Business Network to Fabric Multiple Org as per the tutorial https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org

I have done all the steps exactly as required .

I am getting an error during the **composer ping step**

```
composer network ping -c alice@trade-network
```

> "Error trying to ping. 
>   Error: 2 UNKNOWN: error executing chaincode: transaction returned with
>   failure: Error: The current identity, with the name 'admin' and the
>   identifier
>   '29ab231d7527bdad3784fc6ea332f401e4fa493f1721d7b96621cacde5e34149',
>   has not been registered"

All the previous steps have worked good and the commands succeeded . I am using Composer v0.19

I am guessing the error to this must have been in the exporting the 'trade-network.bna' business definition from composer.bluemix and using it here . 
I am not very sure about this step .

I am using this code script and have changed the code according to the latest composer version and tutorial docs .  https://www.skcript.com/svr/simple-steps-to-run-hyperledger-fabric-composer-network-with-multiple-organization/

I am stuck and not sure how to get rid of this problem ! Please HELP.
Thanks.

Comment: hi, sounds like your CA server does not know of that id and it is not bound to the Network Admin in the business network. You are trying to merge two tutorials so you've gone a custom route (alice is registered with Org1 CA and bob with Org2 CA from the BYFN sample). You have to run `composer identity bind` as an existing participant in the business network. This is the act of the existing business network participants agreeing (via blockchain transaction) that the new business network participant /admin can join and use their identity.

Comment: that helped . thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes i figured it out . i just started the network from the skript tutorial and used the tutorial from the Composer docs for deploying to multiple orgs . The problem did not come this time . 
Maybe the skcript tutorial had old composer based code .

Thanks